# Filter operation with a typeclass return type in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I need to filter a list of items with a function that performs external call and returns a boolean wrapped into something (let's say a `Future`). So basically:

`def filter[A](list: List[A])(f: A => Future[Boolean]): Future[List[A]]`

It seems that this operation can be further generified to something like:

`def filter[F[_], G[_], A](fa: F[A])(f: A => G[Boolean])(implicit T: Traverse[F], ???): G[F[A]]`

I'm struggling to come up with an implementation for this. It does feel like I need a `Traverse[F]` since I'm going to be iterating over the elements, but the transition into `G[F[A]]` is a tricky one to me.

For the `List`/`Future` concrete example, I can think of something like this:

```scala
def filter[A](list: List[A])(f: A => Future[Boolean])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[A]] = {
  val futures: List[Future[(A, Boolean)]] = list.map(a => (a, f(a)))
    .map {
      case (a, future) => future.map(b => (a, b))
    }
  val sequenced: Future[List[(A, Boolean)]] = Future.sequence(futures)
  sequenced.map(l => l.filter((_, b) => b).map((a, _) => a))
}
```

How can I do this in a more generic way? Also I feel like there must be an existing function that does this.

**Edit:**

Quack, here's what I came up with, can it be improved (Scala 3 syntax)?

```scala
def filter[F[_], G[_], A](fa: F[A])(f: A => G[Boolean])(implicit T: Traverse[F], TF: TraverseFilter[F], AF: Applicative[F], AG: Applicative[G]): G[F[A]] =
  val lifted: G[F[A]] = AG.pure(fa)
  val liftedFilterResults: G[F[Boolean]] = T.traverse(fa)(f)
  val liftedZipped: G[F[(A, Boolean)]] = AG.map2(lifted, liftedFilterResults)((a, b) => AF.map2(a, b)((a1, b1) => (a1, b1)))
  val liftedFilteredZipped: G[F[(A, Boolean)]] = AG.map(liftedZipped)(fab => TF.filter(fab)((_: A, b: Boolean) => b))
  AG.map(liftedFilteredZipped)(fab => AF.map(fab)((a, _) => a))
```

Comment: If I have time later, I might take a closer look as a mental exercise. But here's a practical advice: as someone who spent a decade in Scala across five different companies, I learned that there is almost never any real benefit to over-generalizing your code this way. It's good for sharpening your type gymnastics skills, but in production code, it will be much easier to maintain and debug something like `def filter[A](list: List[A])(f: A => Future[Boolean]): Future[List[A]]` than `def filter[F[_], G[_], A](fa: F[A])(f: A => G[Boolean])(implicit T: Traverse[F], ???): G[F[A]]`

Comment: And the boilerplate will only grow, because concrete effects such as `Task`, `IO`, `Future` etc. come with a lot of machinery out-of-the-box. Using a generic `F[_]` with a bunch of typeclasses will be a constant source of pain every time you want to do something new. It's up to you ofc, but personally, I would always always decide on a single library/ecosystem, e.g. cats-effect, and use the concrete type (in that case `IO`).

Comment: This is either `filterA` or `traverseFilter` if you map that `Boolean` into an `Option`: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.typelevel/cats-docs_2.13/latest/cats/TraverseFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of one in cats proper, but `fs2.Stream` does have [`evalFilter`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/co.fs2/fs2-docs_2.13/3.7.0/fs2/Stream.html#evalFilter%5BF2%5Bx%5D%3E:F%5Bx%5D%5D(f:O=%3EF2%5BBoolean%5D):fs2.Stream%5BF2,O%5D) and `evalFilterAsync`

```
val list: List[A] = ???
val filter: A => Future[Boolean] = ???
val result: IO[List[A]] = 
  Stream.emits(list)
    .evalFilter(a => IO.fromFuture(filter(a)))
    // OR .evalFilterAsync(maxConcurrent = 4)(a => IO.fromFuture(filter(a)))
    .compile
    .toList
```